# set multer destination in api.js in nodejs and call another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, multer

i am using a **api** in server.js file.

```
app.post('/api/uploadalumniresume', api.UploadAlumniResume);
```

my api.js file code is:

```
exports.UploadAlumniResume = (req, res) => {
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
      // cb(null, `${__dirname}public/images/uploads`);
      cb(null, `${__dirname}/../public/imports`);
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`);
    },
  });


  const importupload = multer({
    storage,
  });
  const importmulter = importupload.single('file');
};
```

The server.js as call the **api** but the exports api not saving the uploading file to the destination folder

And i need to store the upload file on destination follder.

And if the file as uploaded then function need to work on create fuction in the same api.

please give a any solution to me!

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of your directory structure?